# Link one user to two or more websites

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, eav, multi-website

Can I link one user to two or more websites?. For example, while creating a new customer,we have to select one website from drop down **Associate to Website** as shown

[image]

Here I want to select multiple websites. Is it possible?. If yes, how (I think by changing eav eattribute **website_id** ), and what possible areas to be changed.

Comment: can you explain in details?

Comment: @Abdul please have a look on updated post

Answer (score 0):

In default Magento customer account share two way:

1. Global (Single customer associate to all website)
2. Per Website (associate to individual customer to per website with same email id)

You can configure this feature here: `System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Share Customer Accounts.`

[image]

Comment: currently it is set to "Global", should I set to "Per Website"

Comment: Yes It is set to per website

Comment: Done, then how to assign multiple websites like your screen shot, I am not seeing this in customer creation form, should I add multiple entries for same email id?

Comment: looking not good to me, how it will decide to load which website on front end, because email is same,

Comment: Yes, Your are create same email id per website. Your need to create individual customer per website.

Comment: have you single website in front end?

Comment: Nope, I have multiple websites

Comment: It is decided via website id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51064/discussion-between-abdul-ghaffar-and-abdul).